# Create scatterplot over line plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

So I'm quite new to python and I have to create a **scatterplot** on top of a line plot which I already made using climate data. I already have the dataframe for the scatterplot, which consists of monthly average temperatures for a station between 1837 and 2020.
The line plot shows three graphs describing the mean, min and max temperatures of the period, with the x-axis displaying the months and the y-axis displaying temperature in degrees celsius.
Could anyone please help me which code to use to add the scatterplot on top of the line plot?
(I'm guessing by using **plt.scatter()**)

Comment: I think you are just looking for `plt.plot`: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to plot the scatter and line plots on the same figure, as follows:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig= plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter([random.randint(1, 200) for i in range(100)],
[random.randint(1, 200) for i in range(100)])
ax.plot([1, 200], [1,200])

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Scatter and Line plots')
plt.show()
```

which would in turn return the below plot:

[image]

Comment: Ok great! And how do I set a nominal scale for the x-axis? Should be "jan, feb, mar, apr ..." etc.

Comment: use 
positions=(range(12))
labels=(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep', 'Oct','Nov', 'Dec'])
plt.xticks(positions,labels)

Comment: if the answer has helped you and solved your problem, please accept it as the answer to your question